# CSS / html-pdf issue: Overflow of page

Tags: html, css, node.js, pdf, html-pdf

I have the following very simple HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Test</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using `html-pdf`, I want to produce an A4 PDF file out of the HTML.

```
let data;

var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('test.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'A4' };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('test.pdf', function(err, res) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(res);
});
```

As a result I get a PDF file but it looks like the HTML is cut off.
[image]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `container-fluid` instead of `container`.

`container-fluid` takes up the full width of the viewport and is flexible.

`container` on the other hand takes width with respect to the different breakpoints and is fixed in width for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

In html code instead of

```
<div class="col-md-12">
```

try

```
<div class="col-12">
```

I have tried col-12 in my few web projects, it takes all the width of the parent tag(row wise).